# Transactions in node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

In `node-sqlite3`, if the db is currently in serialized mode, will the next statement wait before the callback of the previous statement finishes, or will the callback run at the same time as the next statement?

What's the best way to write a transaction using `node-sqlite3`? I've thought about these two approaches, but I'm not sure which one is correct, or even if they're both wrong.

```
// NEXT DB STATEMENT WAITS FOR CALLBACK TO COMPLETE?
db.serialize(() => {

    db.run('BEGIN');

    // statement 1
    db.run(
        sql1,
        params1,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return db.serialize(db.run('ROLLBACK'));
            }                           
        }
    );

    // statement 2
    db.run(
        sql2,
        params2,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return db.serialize(db.run('ROLLBACK'));
            }

            return db.serialize(db.run('COMMIT));                               
        }
    );  
});



// NEXT DB STATEMENT DOES NOT WAIT FOR CALLBACK TO COMPLETE?
db.serialize(() => {

    db.run('BEGIN');

    // statement 1
    db.run(
        sql1,
        params1,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return db.serialize(db.run('ROLLBACK'));
            }

            db.serialize(() => {

                // statement 2
                db.run(
                    sql2,
                    params2,
                    (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            return db.serialize(db.run('ROLLBACK'));
                        }

                        return db.serialize(db.run('COMMIT));                               
                    }
                );
            });                             
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: *"will the next statement wait before the callback of the previous statement finishes"* - See the documentation. https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow#databaseserializecallback

Comment: @Tomalak I did, but the documentation doesn't mention what happens to the callbacks. All it states is 'Note that queries scheduled not directly in the callback function are not necessarily serialized', which doesn't answer my original question.

Comment: Hm, I see. I looks like this exact question has been discussed in [node-sqlite3 issue #304](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/304), but the thread is old and inconclusive.

Comment: I'm curious: Are you using my proposed solution? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @Tomalak Though I'm not exactly using it, it did help me a lot. I was already under the famous callback hell, so changing the entire code base now to work with promises would be too much. Therefore, I followed your advice on the start of the answer: a new db connection in serialized mode is opened for each new transaction and closed upon completion, thus guaranteeing no other writes happen to the same connection object.

Comment: Alright, I see. BTW you can use WAL mode to be able to read from the database while transactions are running, if blocked readers are an issue in your use case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and say that `db.serialize()` is a convenience method that does not involve any magic. It should be possible to serialize a batch of statements by waiting until one finishes before sending the next.

This would also work for transactions, **the only thing that must be guaranteed** is that no *other* writes happen to the same `db` connection object while the statements are being run, to keep the transaction clean (as noted in the discussion thread to [node-sqlite3 issue #304](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/304)).

Chaining would be done by strictly calling the next statement in the callback of the previous one, unless the previous one has returned an error, at which point the execution should be stopped.

This is unwieldy when done by *actually* stacking callbacks in the source code. But if we promisify the `Database#run` method, we can use promises:

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

sqlite3.Database.prototype.runAsync = function (sql, ...params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.run(sql, params, function (err) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(this);
        });
    });
};
```

We could have relied on [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) for the promisification, but this would result in the loss of one detail of the `callback` handling in `Database#run` (from [the docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)):

> If execution was successful, the `this` object will contain two properties named `lastID` and `changes` which contain the value of the last inserted row ID and the number of rows affected by this query respectively.

Our custom variant captures the `this` object and returns it as the promise result instead.

With that out of the way, we can define a classic promise chain, kicking off with `BEGIN`, then chaining in any number of statements via `Array#reduce`, and eventually calling `COMMIT` on success or `ROLLBACK` on error:

```js
sqlite3.Database.prototype.runBatchAsync = function (statements) {
    var results = [];
    var batch = ['BEGIN', ...statements, 'COMMIT'];
    return batch.reduce((chain, statement) => chain.then(result => {
        results.push(result);
        return db.runAsync(...[].concat(statement));
    }), Promise.resolve())
    .catch(err => db.runAsync('ROLLBACK').then(() => Promise.reject(err +
        ' in statement #' + results.length)))
    .then(() => results.slice(2));
};
```

As this builds the promise chain, it also builds an array of statement results that it returns when done (minus two items at the start, the first one being `undefined` from `Promise.resolve()`, the second one being the result of `BEGIN`).

Now we can easily pass several statements for serialized execution inside an implicit transaction. Each member of the batch may be either a stand-alone statement, or an array with statement and associated parameters (just as `Database#run` would expect it):

```js
var statements = [
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;",
    "CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT);",
    ["INSERT INTO foo (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);", 1, "First Foo"]
];

db.runBatchAsync(statements).then(results => {
    console.log("SUCCESS!")
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.error("BATCH FAILED: " + err);
});
```

which would log something like this:

```
SUCCESS!
[ { sql: 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;', lastID: 1, changes: 1 },
  { sql: 'CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER NOT NULL, name TEXT);',
    lastID: 1,
    changes: 1 },
  { sql: 'INSERT INTO foo (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);',
    lastID: 1,
    changes: 1 } ]
```

In case of an error, this would cause a roll back, and we would get back the error message from the DB engine, plus *"in statement #X"* where X refers to the statement position in the batch.

Comment: I am thinking to myself: "Dude this is beautiful". I guess I said it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for running transactions using node.js and node-sqlite3, Maybe is not the most otimized, but works for me. The querys are sent through arraySql (Array of sqls) parameter with its parameters (ArrayParams - Array of Arrays of parameters).

```
function db_run_promise(sql, arrayParam) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.run(sql, arrayParam, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                resolve(false);
            }
            else {
                resolve(true);
            }           
        })  
    });
}

function multipleExecSQLWithTransaction(arraySqls, arrayParams) {

    let auxPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const myfunc = async () => {
            db.exec("BEGIN");
            let passed = true;
            for (i = 0; i < arraySqls.length; i++) {
                theSql = arraySqls[i];
                auxResult = await db_run_promise(theSql, arrayParams[i]);
                if (auxResult == false) {
                    passed = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (passed == false) {
                db.exec("ROLLBACK");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                db.exec("COMMIT");
                return true;
            }
        }

        try {
            let aux = myfunc();
            resolve(aux);
        }
        catch (errT) {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });     

    return auxPromise;
}
```